# Javascript objects with nested (internal) methods

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm developing a script in Google-apps ContactsApp to import/modify contacts and take care of duplicates.  I hope my question is clearly expressed since I'm French speaking. This code runs in SpreadsheetApp. I replaced the code `SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(str)` by `alert()` for clarity.

I didn't find exactly what I'm looking for on the forum.

Here is the (simplified) code :

```
function ObjContact(givenName, familyName, email) {
    this.givenName  = givenName;
    this.familyName = familyName;
    this.fullName   = "";
    this.email      = email;
    // other properties snipped

    setFullName(); // declared below

    this.setGivenName = function(str) {
        this.givenName = str;
        setFullName();
        return this;
    }

    this.setFamilyName = function(str) {
        this.familyName= str;
        setFullName();
        return this;
    }

    // I want this function to be accessed only from inside the object
    // by the object itself, to set 
    function setFullName() {
        fullName = givenName + " " + familyName;
        return;
    }
    // other getters and setters snipped
}
```

The question is about the method `setFullName()` that doesn't change the property `fullName`. Using `this.fullName` seems to make the property local to the method. Adding the code `alert(this.givenName);` returns `undefined` but `alert(givenName);` returns the `givenName` correct value. So, I don't understand why `fullName` is never changed...

I'll need other methods to compare and merge duplicate contacts before returning them to the ContactsApp, deleting them.

Comment: function setFullName() {
        this.fullName = this.prenom + " " + this.nom;
        return;
    }

Comment: I translated my variable names to English but forgot this.prenom (translated to this.givenName) and this.nom (translated to this.familyName). Mistake corrected.

Comment: The code you suggest is the one I wrote first. The setter doesn't work and a variable instantiated to ObjContact.fullName returns "".

Comment: Now it should be function setFullName() {
        this.fullName = this.givenName + " " + this.familyName;
    } If it doesn't work for you, please, show how do you call setter and check the value.

Comment: @Roman Granovsky. Thank you Roman. I post the code below in an answer, with the object and the test code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up a pointer to this that will match the parent in the main body of the constructor:

```
var that = this;
```

Then use it in `setFullName()`:

```
function setFullName() {
    that.fullName = givenName + " " + familyName;
    return;
}
```

It seems the `this` in `setFullName()` is a different `this` than in the main body of the constructor.

There's a great tutorial about this subject here: http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html

Comment: Thank you @ebyrob. It works. But there is one thing I don't understand : why is the "that" needed in front of fullName but not in front of givenName and familyName? Thank you for enlighting me please!

Comment: Please, note that edited the original code to correct two variables that were written in French and that I forgot to translate when I posted originaly. this.prenom is now this.givenName and this.nom became this.familyName. Does it change anything? Thank you again.

Comment: @Étienne The context of `this` is different between the main body of the constructor and the internal function.  (`this` refers just to `setFullName()` when internal)

Comment: @Étienne I added a link to a tutorial on the subject.  Note: Variable names shouldn't affect the result as long as they are consistent.

Comment: I absolutely have some scope misunderstanding... Running the method setFullName from within setGivenName() or setFamilyName doesn't alter this.fullName. I have not programmed for 15 years and I am trying my first javascipt objects now. Any cue or accessible reference to suggest? Thanks.

Comment: Thank you so much for posting the tutorial link. Things get clearer!